# How to disable sorting gem names in Gemfile in Rubocop?

Tags: ruby, gemfile, rubocop

I'm coming into a legacy code base which had no style guide. So as to no introduce too many changes, is there a way to by pass this check? https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Bundler/OrderedGems looking at docs and [repo](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20gemfile) didn't yield a solution and trying to exclude Gemfile in rubocop.yml didn't work either.

```
AllCops:                                                                                                                                                                                     
  NewCops: enable                                                                                                                                                                                
  Exclude:                                                                                                                                                                                         
    - Gemfile
```

Comment: If you have many existing offences then you should probably start with the `--auto-gen-config` option to create a todo list: https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html

Answer (score 2):

Add an [exclusion](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html#enabled) for the [`Bundler::OrderedGems`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Bundler/OrderedGems) cop to `.rubocop.yml`:

```yaml
Bundler/OrderedGems:
  Enabled: false
```

Before:

```
$ bin/rubocop Gemfile
Inspecting 1 file
C

Offenses:

Gemfile:14:1: C: [Correctable] Bundler/OrderedGems: Gems should be sorted in an alphabetical order within their section of the Gemfile. Gem puma should appear before rails.
gem 'puma'
^^^^^^^^^^

1 file inspected, 1 offense detected, 1 offense autocorrectable
```

After:

```
$ bin/rubocop Gemfile
Inspecting 1 file
.

1 file inspected, no offenses detected
```

Comment: What's weird is that I haven't added this override and yet Rubocop is not running alphabetic sort on Gemfile, I get no errors even though not sorted.

Comment: @lacostenycoder [Run rubocop with debug flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72548328/3784008) to see what configuration files are being picked up. It's possible something not immediately obvious is causing that.

Comment: yeah, that didn't yield anything, it passed with no offenses and `- '**/*.gemfile' ` shows included in the default.yml  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: reading the description, am I seeing correctly that it only sorts within groups, but not flat gems not within a group?

Comment: No, the example I gave was a Gemfile with just flat gems.